# Calling Story Board data - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` that I am trying to access from one of my `ViewControllers` to the other.

Here is what I am doing:

`a.h`:

```
#import "b.h"
.....
@property(nonatomic,strong) b *viewControllers;
```

`a.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    _viewControllers = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"createChallengeInfo"];
    .....code....
}
....code....
-(IBAction)sendVideo:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.viewControllers.selectedCells);
}
```

Now when `logging` this I encounter an error, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address =0x13765350)`.

Here is my other `ViewController`.

`b.h`:

```
...code....
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedCells; <-- this is the array I want to access
...code...
```

`b.m`:

```
#import "a.h"
...import...
@interface b ()

@end

@implementation b
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* INITIATE VARIABLE */

    _selectedCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ....code....
}
...code...
```

So my issue is accessing, `selectedCells`.  But firstly why am I getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?  And secondly before I get the `error` It lays out the `ViewController` and shows the variable `selectedCells` as nil.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Is your create_challenge_peopleSelect view controller visible when you log NSLog(@"%@",self.viewControllers.selectedCells); ?

Comment: @Greg yes I can see the `ViewController` in the log.  just all the values are nil.

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking have you loaded the view controller to the view hierarchy when you call NSLog?

Comment: Does *storyboard go out of scope here?

Comment: @greg in the `viewDidLoad` in `a.m`?

Comment: @stevesliva what do you mean?

Comment: In viewDidLoad I can see that you just instantiate view controller but you haven't load it to view hierarchy (you don't present or push it). If you haven't present the view viewDidLoad isn't fired and _selectedCell is nil.

Comment: @Greg I assumed it is being initiated because `a` `ViewContainer` contains a `container` that `b` is embed to.

Comment: Add log to viewDidLoad in b class and check it out.

Comment: @greg in my `b` class?  Or my `a` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "b" is embedded in a container view of "a", then it is already instantiated when "a" gets instantiated. Therefore, when you use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, you are creating a new instance, NOT the one you have on screen. Your viewDidLoad should look like this instead,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _viewControllers = self.childViewControllers[0];
    .....code....
}
```

Another way to get a reference to the embedded view controller is in prepareForSegue, which will be called right after your "a" controller is instantiated. Your "b" controller will be  segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: but to use `prepareForSegue` you have to send it to that `viewController` and I don't want that,

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "you have to send it to that view controller?. prepareForsegue is called for the embed segue that your "b" controller is in. segue.destinationViewController and self.childViewControllers[0] should point to the same object.